# Display iframe value at textbox in php

Tags: php, html, iframe

I have insert iframe value into my database using php. I need to display the inserted value in a textbox in another page. But while displaying the data it only displays the value till the first " in the iframe.

my code

```
<label>Location</label>  <input type="text" style="resize:vertical" class="md-input" name="locationmap"  class="md-input" value="<?php echo $comp_row['comp_locationmap']?>">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin form-control-feedback glyphiconalign"></i> </div>
```

The output textbox only displays `"<iframe src= "`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to escape the special characters!

you can do this by using htmlspecialchars() to convert only special characters to HTML entities

```
echo htmlspecialchars($comp_row['comp_locationmap']);
```

or htmlentities() to convert all characters to HTML entities

```
echo htmlentities($comp_row['comp_locationmap']);
```